# View's init is called only once in tabview SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am making an app where I am updating profile picture in profileView tab for current user. Then I am navigating to feedView tab where I am expecting change of profile picture in each post related to the current-user. But in the feedview profile picture is not updating. If I rerun the app I see the changes in the feed view correctly.

So I debugged the app, and found that, init() of a FeedCellview inside a tabview is called only for the first time. While I am using the app and navigate to Feedview, init is not being called, and thus I can not update data from the viewmodel.

MainView:

```
var body: some View {
        TabView (selection: $tabSelection){
            NavigationView{
                FeedView()
                    .navigationTitle("Feed")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: logoutButton)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
            }.tag(1)
            ...................
            ...................
```

FeedView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject private var feedViewModel = FeedViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(){
            LazyVStack(spacing:32){
                ForEach(feedViewModel.posts){post in
                    FeedCellView(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FeedCellView:

```
struct FeedCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var feedCellViewModel:FeedCellViewModel
    
    init(viewModel:FeedCellViewModel){
        self.feedCellViewModel = viewModel //This init is not being called after first time
        print("feed Cell View Init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            
            if let user = feedCellViewModel.post.user{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ProfileView(user: user),
                    label: {
                        HStack{
                            if let imageUrl = feedCellViewModel.post.ownerImageUrl{
                                KFImage(URL(string: imageUrl))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width:36,height: 36)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .cornerRadius(18)
                            }else{
                                Image("profile-placeholder")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width:36,height: 36)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .cornerRadius(18)
                            }
................
................
```

FeedCellViewModel:

```
class FeedCellViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var post:PostModel
    
    init(post:PostModel){
        self.post = post
        fetchUser()
        checkLike()
    }
    
    func fetchUser(){
        print("Feed cell ViewModel fetchUser called")
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(post.ownerId).getDocument { (snap, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.post.user = try? snap?.data(as: UserModel.self)
                guard let userImageUrl = self.post.user?.profileImageUrl else{return}
                self.post.ownerImageUrl = userImageUrl
                print("OwnerImageUrl \(self.post.ownerUsername): \(self.post.ownerImageUrl ?? "No Image Url")")
            }
            
        }
    }
............................
............................
```

Why `init()` is called only once in FeedCellVIew? I am using Xcode 12.2.

Comment: There is no specification how many times SwiftUI view's init should be called, it can be any (from 1 to infinity) - you should not depend on that, just make it as light as possible.

Comment: Then how will I pass data (coming from parent view) from view to its viewModel?